# jQuery click function on gridview tr

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Im working on a project that filters lots of infomation into a gridview, this gridview is inside an updatepanel and i got the RowDataBound event programmed to set a css class on each row since doing it manualy doesen´t seem to work... The class gets added but i now need to toggle a class on tr click. I've been trying with jQuery but it doesen't seems to work (it works perfectly on elements outside the table).

[Fiddle of what I want](https://jsfiddle.net/86coxqr1/)

Heres my gridview

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gridTabla" runat="server" BorderColor="White" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F0F0F0" BorderColor="#F0F0F0" BorderStyle="Solid" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="codesc" DataField="CodEscuela" HeaderText="Cod" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="esc" DataField="Escuela" HeaderText="Escuela" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="codar" DataField="codCarrera" HeaderText="Cod" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="car" DataField="Carrera" HeaderText="Carrera" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="codmat" DataField="codMateria" HeaderText="Cod" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="materia" DataField="Materia" HeaderText="Materia" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="nom" DataField="Nomina" HeaderText="Nomina" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="prof" DataField="Profesor" HeaderText="Profesor" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="noalumnos" DataField="noAlumnos" HeaderText="Numero de alumnos" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="noregistros" DataField="noRegistros" HeaderText="Numero de Registros" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="periodo" DataField="Periodo" HeaderText="Periodo" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="np" DataField="NP" HeaderText="NP" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="ni" DataField="NI" HeaderText="NI" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="diez" DataField="Diez" HeaderText="10" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="nueve" DataField="Nueve" HeaderText="9" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="ocho" DataField="Ocho" HeaderText="8" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="siete" DataField="Siete" HeaderText="7" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="seis" DataField="Seis" HeaderText="6" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="cinco" DataField="Cinco" HeaderText="5" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="bantutor" DataField="BandTutor" HeaderText="Reportes de tutor" />
                <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="banddir" DataField="BandDirector" HeaderText="Reportes de director" />
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle BorderStyle="None" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My RowDataBound

```
Protected Sub gridTabla_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gridTabla.RowDataBound
  e.Row.CssClass = "clickableTr"
End Sub
```

And my jQuery function

```
$('.clickableTr').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('activeTr');
});
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong, this works perfectly on outer-table elements

Comment: can you please copy and paste your html code here..  f12 or inspect element to get the code..

Comment: its quite a lot... and im not actually allowed to share most of that information

Comment: i just wanted to know the table formatted correctly.. can you please create a demo html

Comment: Try this: `$('#gridTabla').on('click','.clickableTr', function(){$(this).toggleClass('activeTr');})`

Comment: What is the container of this `UpdatePanel5`? Any _id_ so that it can be selected by _jQuery_?

Comment: @Wellwisher I cant create a demo of my project because im using asp.net, i think its a bit complicated

Comment: @mshsayem Yeap, that did it, thanks!

Comment: @mshsayem i used `document`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `UpdatePanel` which gets updated on postback. But your javascript registers the event for just first time. When an update is occurred, the event registration is gone. You'll need to use `on` instead of `click` to handle this. Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#gridTabla").on("click", ".clickableTr", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("activeTr");
    });
});
```